# SonarQube - Security Rules Plugin not showing active rules

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to get the security rules plug-in working.  As it stands, it shows 0/55 rules are activated.  I have a blend of rules from findbugs to vbnet

below is an example of how i have them enterd.

fxcop-vbnet:RoleManagerCookieProtectionShouldBeAll,findbugs:DMI_CONSTANT_DB_PASSWORD

I have tried with a no space after the comma, a space after the comma and for

What am i missing?